# Drupal commerce / Commerce Pricelist with Prices per Store. How to use the default currency from the store in the variation type?

Tags: commerce

We have Drupal Commerce 2 stores using commerce pricelist for store-specific prices.
Each store represents a country. Prices are working fine so far, but static in EUR.
But how can we provide the prices in british pound for the UL Store ?
Each store has a default currency, how can we connect this to the displayed price
in the product variation type ?

thxinadvance Tobi

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you fine a solution?

Comment: Not yet. We decided to deal with UK issues later on and do anything in EUR.

Comment: I just found a solution using Commerce Currency Resolver. Now am able to display each currency based on either its store or country.